# How to remove ckeck box checked item of recyclerview on button click?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want to update my recyclerview list dynamically.
My list data is shown and when I select the checkbox and click on the button at that time selected item is removed and store it in an array. so plz help me how to do this.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, how it goes:

- First create a model which contains data for your list with a boolean flag with true and false value for checkbox property.
- During click of the recyclerview row button check whether checkbox is checked. And if it is checked then write this code:

> yourList.remove(position)
>       notifyItemRemoved(position)